# Notification App name need to change

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal

Can we change or Remove app name from an android notification?[image]

Comment: Do you have example of any app with that behavior? Because it's up to system to parse posted notifications, and they usually show app name.

Comment: Please change your application name from values/strings.xml file

Comment: you can't change that. It is a way to show which app shows the notification. You shouldn't be able to show the notification as from another app.

Answer (score 0):

Change name of your android app. Go to Android project > Right Clik > Properties > AndroidManifest > change your Application Name.